# Python: os.path.isfile returns TRUE even if file does not exist yet (before shutil.copyfile)

Tags: python, csv, copy, shutil

I'm fairly new to Python (about 3 weeks) and working on copying files based on a csv list. I just can't figure out why os.path.isfile() returns TRUE in my code, even if the file is not existing yet, before i copy using shutil within an if condition.

I loop through the source (src) and target (tgt) from a data frame converted from a csv and assign the target os.path.isfile() to a variable, TGT_EXIST to check for the target file. I even forced it to 'False' for the meantime to check how it changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import shutil

df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
#     Read csv rows
    src = row['Source']
    tgt = row['Target']

    TGT_EXIST = False
    
    print("Test 0", TGT_EXIST)
#     Check Target filepath if pre-existing
    TGT_EXIST = os.path.isfile(tgt)
    print("Test 00", TGT_EXIST)    
    print(tgt)    
    if TGT_EXIST and filecmp.cmp(src, tgt):
        print("Target : Exists, same.")
    elif TGT_EXIST and  not filecmp.cmp(src, tgt):
        print("Target : Exists, not same. Will not copy.")
    elif not TGT_EXIST:
        print("Target : Not exists. Copying...")
        shutil.copyfile(src, tgt)
```

Based on my test prints below, 'Test 0' and 'Test 00', TGT_EXIST returns True after assigning the variable,
even if it does not exist yet, even if I shift-deleted it from the target folder before running again, even before the shutil.copyfile() elif condition. It goes directly to the first if condition, "Target : Exists, same."

`Test 0 False Test 00 True F:\TEST COPY2018\20181231\DMC-LX7\P1070674.MP4 Target : Exists, same.`

However, this is not the case when i comment out the shutil.copyfile(src, tgt) line in the third if condition, elif not TGT_EXIST:

`Test 0 False Test 00 False F:\TEST COPY2018\20181231\DMC-LX7\P1070674.MP4 Target : Not exists. Copying..`

I have no other shutil.copyfile() other than what's in the if condition, so im confused as to why it copies ahead or returns True even before copying. (I've also restarted the kernel in jupyter to flush out the variables)

I only have 2 test files, so does the script process that fast that it executes the copy while testing the  target file? Or is there a more precise why on writing the if condition?

Appreciate any inputs. Thank you.

Comment: Strange. I switched from Windows to Mac OS and re-ran my code,  and the behavior seem to have 'corrected' itself.  TGT_EXIST variable correctly maps False on my first run (target file not yet copied).

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're seeing is most likely due to the fact that os.path.isfile() checks if a file exists based on its path. It doesn't take into account whether the file is open or not. So, even if you delete the file before calling os.path.isfile(), it may still return True if the file is open in another process or application.

In your case, it's possible that the file is still open in the background and the OS has not yet fully released its handle, causing os.path.isfile() to return True. When you comment out the shutil.copyfile() line, the file is not being opened and closed by your program, which may explain why os.path.isfile() returns False in that case.

One way to work around this issue is to use a try-except block around the shutil.copyfile() call, catching the FileNotFoundError that would be raised if the file doesn't exist. For example:

```
    shutil.copyfile(src, tgt)
    print("Target : Copied.")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Target : Not found.")
```